# in Studio or Flex gow to use a real phone number for a client

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

Created a short version in Studio or Flex unsure if these are the same or separate. but it created a trial account but cannot do what the client wants and must use existing local phone number client would get mad If I show them a Georgia phone number because if Georgia Boycott they will not do business with Georgia Period and Twilio assign us a Georgia prefix for trial. they will not want to do business with me or Twilio if I buy Georgia numbers. Why can I not just assign a phone number I already have Bought for them on Twilio in California? Cannot sell to them without using the phone number they already purchased.

Comment: reluctant to upgrade as if it sticks me with the Georgia Phone number I cannot show the client for input. or they would stop working with me because of Georgia Boycott. Zero of Clients customers would call or do business with them if they publish this number.

Comment: Cancel or release a Twilio number - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183028-Cancel-or-release-a-Twilio-number

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Do not worry, you do not need to keep your Georgia number if you don't want it.

The number that Twilio assigns to you when you create a Flex project can be changed, you do not need to keep the one that is automatically assigned and you can [release it](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183028-Cancel-or-release-a-Twilio-number).

You say that you have a number that you already bought. You can transfer your number from one account to your Flex project, just follow the instructions here:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020243334-Move-or-Transfer-a-Phone-Number-to-your-Flex-Project